# “SELECT DISTINCT” ignores different cases in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need the output from the following query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ("A", "a", "b", "B")
```

O/P should be:

```
"A", "B"
```

From `'A'` and `'a'` only single entry should become.

But in hive I have:

```
"A", "a", "b", "B"
```

In sql there is something like:

```
Select distinct col1 COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
From dbo.myTable;
```

Is there anything like: `'sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as'` in hive or any alternative query to that?

Answer (score 2):

may be you have to ignore case like below.

**select distinct ucase(id) from myTable;**

see [string functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) in hive .

If it does not solve your purpose then you have to create [custom user defined function](http://learnthejava.blogspot.in/2012/02/hive-custom-user-defined-function-udf.html) in Java

Comment: Thanks, But it is converts the data to uppercase. My requirement is original case should not be change.

Comment: at least in your example above, the case *must* change since you want to return a single value for both 'a' and 'A'.  no?